# Split strings in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 2-D tensor of strings having dimension `[None, None]`. I want to split each string using `tf.string_split()` function. I have tried using the below code

```
sentences = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, None], dtype=tf.string)
# remove punctuation
normalized_sentences = tf.regex_replace(input=sentences, pattern=r"\pP", rewrite="")        
tokens = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.string_split(x, delimiter=" "), normalized_sentences, dtype=tf.string)
```

But the error throws me an error.

```
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("map/while/StringSplit:0", shape=(?, 2), dtype=int64), values=Tensor("map/while/StringSplit:1", shape=(?,), dtype=string), dense_shape=Tensor("map/while/StringSplit:2", shape=(2,), dtype=int64)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Comment: Did you mean a 1-D tensor? For example `tf.constant(["ab", "cde"])` is a batch of string of shape `[2]`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of [`tf.string_split(x)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_split) use `tf.string_split(x).values`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

print(tf.string_split(['this is example sentence']).values)
# tf.Tensor([b'this' b'is' b'example' b'sentence'], shape=(4,), dtype=string)
```