# Split Strings from Tensorflow CSV serving function

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I have a processing function for some feature logic which involves string splitting.

A working Tensors from a datasets: `<tf.Tensor 'arg0:0' shape=(1,) dtype=string>`

An invalid Tensor from the serving function: `<tf.Tensor 'DecodeCSV:1' shape=(?, 1) dtype=string>`

Serving function:

```
def csv_serving_input_fn():
    csv_row = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string)
    features = parse_csv(csv_row, is_serving=True)
    ...
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(
        features=process_features(features),
        receiver_tensors={'csv_row': csv_row}
    )
```

Parse Function

```
def parse_csv(csv_row, is_serving=False):
    columns = tf.decode_csv(tf.expand_dims(csv_row, -1), record_defaults=HEADER_DEFAULTS)
    return dict(zip(HEADER, columns))
```

The failure for shape (?,)

```
def process_features(features):
    x = tf.string_split(features['text'])
    ....
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 2 for 'StringSplit' (op: 'StringSplit') with input shapes: [?,1], [].
```

What would be the correct serving function?

Similar Issue:
[Split strings in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54108911/split-strings-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Try to take a look at our template: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/cloudml-template/examples/classification/census/trainer/inputs.py here.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not very clear regarding this but [string_split](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/string_split) is used for rank 1 Vectors.

Use [strings.split](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strings/split) instead.